# Spatie role and permission error when using middleware('auth:sanctum')

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, middleware, roles

When I'm creating new users and assign them roles and permissions it works fine,
but when I assign role using protected route

```php
Route::post('/excel/upload', [ExcelController::class,'upload'])->name('uploadExcel')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

i get and error:
Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\GuardDoesNotMatch
The given role or permission should use guard `web` instead of `sanctum`.

auth.php

```
    'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

the guard_name in the Spatie role and permissions tables set to web.

I understand that there's a problem with the guard_name configuration, I just can't
figure out how to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using a different model from the used one in providers.users.model?

Comment: please see https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1540#issuecomment-672727356

Answer (score 0):

Insert the below code to auth/config.php file

```
'guards' => [
...

'sanctum' => [
    'driver' => 'sanctum',
    'provider' => 'users'
]
```

],